# liquibase: trying to rollback using maven in eclipse, getting MojoFailureException although mvn clean install working fine

Tags: java, spring, maven, liquibase

i am trying to learn liquibase with one demo project, i have configured a pretty basic application, and wanted to see how liquibase works, was able to make changesets work properly, now stuck on the rollback part, i have defined the tags and context and using eclipse to run the maven update for rollback, but keep on getting below exception. kindly help.

```
 Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:4.24.0:rollback (default-cli) on project liquibase: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Failed to resolve the properties file.: The file liquibase/src/main/resources/application.properties was not found in the configured search path:
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\Desktop\liquibase\liquibase\target\classes
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\3.2.1\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-3.2.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\3.2.1\spring-boot-starter-aop-3.2.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\6.1.2\spring-aop-6.1.2.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.21\aspectjweaver-1.9.21.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\3.2.1\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-3.2.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\5.0.1\HikariCP-5.0.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\6.1.2\spring-jdbc-6.1.2.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\orm\hibernate-core\6.4.1.Final\hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\3.1.0\jakarta.persistence-api-3.1.0.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\2.0.1\jakarta.transaction-api-2.0.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.5.3.Final\jboss-logging-3.5.3.Final.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.6.0\classmate-1.6.0.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\antlr\antlr4-runtime\4.13.0\antlr4-runtime-4.13.0.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\3.2.1\spring-data-jpa-3.2.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\3.2.1\spring-data-commons-3.2.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\6.1.2\spring-orm-6.1.2.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\6.1.2\spring-context-6.1.2.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\6.1.2\spring-tx-6.1.2.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\6.1.2\spring-beans-6.1.2.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\2.0.9\slf4j-api-2.0.9.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\6.1.2\spring-aspects-6.1.2.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-validation\3.2.1\spring-boot-starter-validation-3.2.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\3.2.1\spring-boot-starter-3.2.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\3.2.1\spring-boot-3.2.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\3.2.1\spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\3.2.1\spring-boot-starter-logging-3.2.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.4.14\logback-classic-1.4.14.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.4.14\logback-core-1.4.14.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.21.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.21.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.21.1\log4j-api-2.21.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\2.0.9\jul-to-slf4j-2.0.9.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\10.1.17\tomcat-embed-el-10.1.17.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\8.0.1.Final\hibernate-validator-8.0.1.Final.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\jakarta\validation\jakarta.validation-api\3.0.2\jakarta.validation-api-3.0.2.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\3.2.1\spring-boot-starter-web-3.2.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\3.2.1\spring-boot-starter-json-3.2.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.15.3\jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.15.3\jackson-annotations-2.15.3.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.15.3\jackson-core-2.15.3.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.15.3\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.15.3.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.15.3\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.15.3.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.15.3\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.15.3.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\6.1.2\spring-web-6.1.2.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-observation\1.12.1\micrometer-observation-1.12.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-commons\1.12.1\micrometer-commons-1.12.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\6.1.2\spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\6.1.2\spring-expression-6.1.2.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\liquibase\liquibase-core\4.24.0\liquibase-core-4.24.0.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\com\opencsv\opencsv\5.8\opencsv-5.8.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.13.0\commons-lang3-3.13.0.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-text\1.10.0\commons-text-1.10.0.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-collections4\4.4\commons-collections4-4.4.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\2.2\snakeyaml-2.2.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.3.1\jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.30\lombok-1.18.30.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\3.2.1\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-3.2.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\2.1.1\jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\10.1.17\tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\10.1.17\tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.17.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\6.1.2\spring-core-6.1.2.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\6.1.2\spring-jcl-6.1.2.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\com\microsoft\sqlserver\mssql-jdbc\12.4.2.jre11\mssql-jdbc-12.4.2.jre11.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.14.10\byte-buddy-1.14.10.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\junit\jupiter\junit-jupiter-params\5.10.1\junit-jupiter-params-5.10.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\junit\jupiter\junit-jupiter\5.10.1\junit-jupiter-5.10.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\assertj\assertj-core\3.24.2\assertj-core-3.24.2.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\objenesis\objenesis\3.3\objenesis-3.3.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm\9.3\asm-9.3.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\apiguardian\apiguardian-api\1.1.2\apiguardian-api-1.1.2.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy-agent\1.14.10\byte-buddy-agent-1.14.10.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\4.1.2\istack-commons-runtime-4.1.2.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\com\jayway\jsonpath\json-path\2.8.0\json-path-2.8.0.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\mockito\mockito-core\5.7.0\mockito-core-5.7.0.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest\2.2\hamcrest-2.2.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\4.0.1\jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\2.1.2\jakarta.activation-api-2.1.2.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\junit\platform\junit-platform-engine\1.10.1\junit-platform-engine-1.10.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\com\vaadin\external\google\android-json\0.0.20131108.vaadin1\android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\jakarta\inject\jakarta.inject-api\2.0.1\jakarta.inject-api-2.0.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-test\3.2.1\spring-boot-starter-test-3.2.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\junit\jupiter\junit-jupiter-api\5.10.1\junit-jupiter-api-5.10.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\4.0.4\txw2-4.0.4.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\awaitility\awaitility\4.2.0\awaitility-4.2.0.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\net\minidev\json-smart\2.5.0\json-smart-2.5.0.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\angus\angus-activation\2.0.1\angus-activation-2.0.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\xmlunit\xmlunit-core\2.9.1\xmlunit-core-2.9.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\6.0.6.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-6.0.6.Final.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\junit\platform\junit-platform-commons\1.10.1\junit-platform-commons-1.10.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\junit\jupiter\junit-jupiter-engine\5.10.1\junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-core\4.0.4\jaxb-core-4.0.4.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\mockito\mockito-junit-jupiter\5.7.0\mockito-junit-jupiter-5.7.0.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\4.0.4\jaxb-runtime-4.0.4.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-test-autoconfigure\3.2.1\spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-3.2.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\net\minidev\accessors-smart\2.5.0\accessors-smart-2.5.0.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-test\3.2.1\spring-boot-test-3.2.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\skyscreamer\jsonassert\1.5.1\jsonassert-1.5.1.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\io\smallrye\jandex\3.1.2\jandex-3.1.2.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\opentest4j\opentest4j\1.3.0\opentest4j-1.3.0.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\Desktop\liquibase\liquibase\target\test-classes
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-test\6.1.2\spring-test-6.1.2.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\com\mysql\mysql-connector-j\8.1.0\mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\liquibase\liquibase-maven-plugin\4.24.0\liquibase-maven-plugin-4.24.0.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.12.0\commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\.m2\repository\org\liquibase\liquibase-commercial\4.24.0\liquibase-commercial-4.24.0.jar
[ERROR]     - C:\Users\japr3002\Desktop\liquibase\liquibase
[ERROR] More locations can be added with the 'searchPath' parameter.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

below is the code base that i am using

path for application.properties : /liquibase/src/main/resources/application.properties

application.properties

```
spring.liquibase.enabled=true

spring.liquibase.change-log=db/changelog/changelog-master.xml
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=liquibasedb;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=admin_master_1
spring.jpa.hibernate.dd-auto=none
```

changelog-master.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.8.xsd">

    <include file="db/changelog/changelog-versions/changelog-v01.xml"/>
    <changeSet id="liquibase_demo_v2" author="prafull">
        <tagDatabase tag="v2.0" />
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

changelog-v01.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- version 1 changes -->
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.8.xsd">

    <changeSet id="liquibase_demo_1" author="prafull">
        <sqlFile
            path="classpath:db/changelog/sql-script/database_demo.sql" />
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet id="liquibase_demo_1_rollback" author="prafull"
        context="rollbackContext">
        <rollback>
            <sqlFile
                path="classpath:db/changelog/rollback-scripts/rollback1.sql" />
        </rollback>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet id="liquibase_demo_2" author="prafull" runOnChange="true">
        <sqlFile
            path="classpath:db/changelog/sql-script/database_insertion.sql" />
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet id="liquibase_demo_2_rollback" author="prafull"
        context="rollbackcontext">
        <rollback>
            <sqlFile
                path="classpath:db/changelog/rollback-scripts/rollback2.sql" />
        </rollback>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet id="liquibase_demo_v2_1" author="prafull">
        <sqlFile
            path="classpath:db/changelog/sql-script/database_demo_v2.sql" />
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet id="liquibase_demo_inside_v1" author="prafull">
        <sqlFile
            path="classpath:db/changelog/sql-script/database_demo_inside_v1.sql" />
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

pom.xml

```
.
.
.
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
.
.
.
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFile>
                        liquibase/src/main/resources/application.properties</propertyFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

kindly let me know if any further information is required.

maven goal i'm using: liquibase:rollback -Dliquibase.rollbackTag=v2.0
tried from maven command line as well as run as-> maven build-> configuration from eclipse